# "Website not configured at this address" upon Foreman start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

World,

Doing some work with a company on a rails app that uses Foreman gem.  My current setup is Mac OSX El Capitan, Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.3.0, Postgresql.

The app is listening at port 5000, and i've configred my etc/hosts file accordingly. (added a 0.0.0.0 line) and updated my puma.rb file to local host - 5000.

After starting postgres, and Foreman successfully, I am getting a "Website could not be configured at this address" error.

I've seen other threads where "clearing browser cache" was a quick way to fix this issue. But this has not fixed it for me, and I am leaning toward this being a problem with foreman/the app environment.

Any advice/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure this is not a browser issue I would try to load the app from a clean environment using the "private browsing" feature of your browser (CTRL+SHIFT+N on google chrome).

Comment: Hi @TopperH, I'll go ahead and give this a shot when I get home and report back. appreciate the feedback.

Comment: still no go after loading app while incognito

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was simply using the wrong localhost url. The app that I am working on is listening at 5000 so i had to take the following steps to fix:

1. Update the /etc/hosts file with the 0.0.0.0 "mysitesname.dev"
2. use the url of: http://mysites.name.dev:5000

All is well :) I hope that someone else may find this helpful.